# Getting extra data from named pipe, C program (writer) and Python (reader)

Tags: python, c, linux, named-pipes

I have a C program that is writing to a named pipe which is just outputting strings and a "/n" character as a delimiter. When I read from this named pipe using another C program my string comes back as expected. I have a python script which is what I want to be reading the named pipe with. It get's the proper string but also outputs lots of other garage data along with it including device descriptors.

EDIT: I should note I'm working with named-pipes on linux

Here's the C program reader which works fine:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/testpipe";
    char buf[MAX_BUF];


    while(1){
            /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
            fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
            read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
            printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
            close(fd);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

and the python version:

```
import os
import errno

FIFO = '/tmp/testpipe'

try:
    os.mkfifo(FIFO)
except OSError as oe:
    if oe.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise

while True:
    with open(FIFO) as fifo:
        for line in fifo:
            print('{0}',line)
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
('{0}', 'systime=1523890481 ch=25 LAP=c969d3 err=0 clkn=286140 clk_offset=954 s=-68 n=-55 snr=-13\n')
('{0}', "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x97\xfav(\xdc\xf7~\xc0\xf3\xd1v\x96\x06\x00\x00,\xdc\xf7~$F\xf8v\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb4e\xd2v\x96\x06\x00\x00\x04\x88\xd2v\xa0\x97\xfav,\xdc\xf7~\x18\xdc\xf7~L\xdd\xf7~ \xdc\xf7~T\xdd\xf7~S\xed\xf7~ \xdc\xf7~\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x0f\x00\x00T\xdd\xf7~\xc8\xdc\xf7~\x01\x00\x00\x00P@L\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xb9\xdfv\x00\x00\x00\x00L\xdd\xf7~\x01\x80\xad\xfbT\xdd\xf7~T\xdd\xf7~T\xdd\xf7~T\xdd\xf7~z\xdd\xf7~S\xed\xf7~T\xdd\xf7~S\xed\xf7~\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x97\xfav\xc0\xdc\xf7~\xdc\xed\xd1v\x1d\x05\x00\x00\xc4\xdc\xf7~$F\xf8v\x01\x00\x00\x00$N\xd2v\x1d\x05\x00\x00\x04\x88\xd2v\xa0\x97\xfav\xc4\xdc\xf7~\xc0\xdc\xf7~\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf0\xac\xfav\x04\x88\xd2vT\xfc\xd1v\x06n\x0e\xc4ps \x06\x82\x0b\xf1v\x90\xf5\xf0v0\x89\xf9v\xf0\xac\xfav0\xdd\xf7~\x88\xb8\xfav\xbcr\xf9v\x00\xb0\xfav\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00W\xfav\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf4\xdd\xf7~\x06n\x0e\xc4\xd0\x93\xfav\x00\x00\x00\x000\xdd\xf7~8\xdd\xf7~\xa4\xdd\xf7~\x82\x0b\xf1v\x8c\xdd\xf7~\xfcK\xf8v8\xdd\xf7~\xbc\xba\xfav\x05\x00\x00\x00XX\xfav\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x18\x92\xfav\xe8\xac\xfav\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00T\xdd\xf7~\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xd0\x93\xfav\x18\x92\xfav\xff\xff\xff\xffp\xcc\xddv$N\xd2v\xa0\x97\xfav\xe0\x13\xf2v\xc8\x13\xf2v |M\x00\xd4 \xf2vD[\xe5v/sys\x00\x00\x00\x00/usb/devices/1-1\x00\xf0\xf0vl@\x02\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00`d\xfav\x00\x00\x00\x00P@L\x00\xf8\xdd\xf7~\x0c\x00\x00\x00\xe8\xa1\xf8vXX\xfav\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00/1-1$N\xd2v \xcaM\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\xe8\xac\xfav \xcaM\x00\xf4\xdd\xf7~\xe8\xac\xfav\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P@L\x00p\xcc\xddv\xcc\x9c\xf1v\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x14\xf2v\xd0\x1d\xf2v\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x15\x00\x00\x01\x0c\xf5\xf8'/dev/bus/usb/001/004\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")
```

What is the difference in reading from the named pipe between these two programs?

Comment: I guess your writing C program has a bug just like a reading C program that you've shown here. You need to check return codes of all the c functions `open` `read` etc. otherwise it may be printing values of uninitialized buffer. I also suspect that you are writing entire buffer with whatever garbage comes after the terminating char.

Comment: `while True:` ???? Please, post a [mcve].

Comment: @Stargateur `while True` makes perfect sense if the FIFO can get closed but will be fed more data later

Comment: @user234461 Yeah, super, all can make sense, but do you see something like that in the actual code ? No. We shouldn't make assumption about code that is not here.

Comment: @Stargateur yes

Comment: @Stargateur which is why the _Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable_ never makes sense `We shouldn't make assumption about code that is not here` . You either want my 1,000s lines of code for controlling a FIFO or a very small example which can duplicate the result.

Comment: Always, *always*, check return value of a function like `read`. When printing data received from non-string function (like `read` here), always make sure you either specify correct data length (returned by `read` here!), or make sure there is string-terminating null there (you still need return value of `read` to do this).

Comment: @HereNowWhy Reduce your code to the minimal is VERY good, but I just wondering why you keep this strange infinite loop in this case. How should I know that this loop make sense in your original code ? Please give the code that write the pipe.

Comment: @Stargateur Yeah I see what you're saying I think I brain farted when trying to create this simple example. I'm simplifying the writer code now.

Answer (score 2):

C recognises `\x00` (the NUL character) as the end of a string (see: c-string), but Python does not. The garbage was always there in the FIFO, so your C-based writer is sending garbage to the FIFO for some reason (which we will never know because you haven't posted that code).

Comment: I'm voting to close the question. I have a similar question and the OP having no interest in answering your query makes his question a false trail.